# how can I use a variable from a class in another file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 scripts, 1 holds the Log file creation and another script holds the email configuration. I need to pass a variable from the log file creation script to the send email script, I have imported the Log file to the send email script `from LogFile import LogFileT`:

Log code:

```
import configparser
from configparser import RawConfigParser
import codecs
import unittest
import time
import sys
import logging


config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
configFilePath = 'C:\\Python\\PI_WebUITesting\\EnvConfig.cfg'
config.read(configFilePath)

class LogFileT:
    def log_file(log_name):
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        timestemp = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        logfilename = config.get('EnvConfig', 'logfile_path') + timestr + log_name
        logging.basicConfig(filename=logfilename, filemode='w',format= timestemp + '--%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

SendEmail code:

```
import configparser
from configparser import RawConfigParser
import codecs
import unittest
import time
import sys
import logging
import trace
import smtplib,ssl
import base64
from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from LogFile import LogFileT

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
configFilePath = 'C:\\Python\\PI_WebUITesting\\EnvConfig.cfg'
config.read(configFilePath)

class SendEmail:        
    def send_mail(self,email_subject):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        send_from = (config.get('MailConfig', 'send_from'))
        send_to = (config.get('MailConfig', 'send_to'))
        email_filename = LogFile.logfilename
        msg['From'] = send_from
        msg['To'] = send_to
        msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
        msg['Subject'] = email_subject
        msg.attach(MIMEText(email_filename))
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open(email_filename, "rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="PI_Test.log"')
        msg.attach(part)
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP(config.get('MailConfig', 'smtp'))
        smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
        smtp.quit()
```

I need the `logfilename` from the Log class to add it to `email_filename` on the Send Email code.

can someone assist please?

Comment: Are you sure that the class in the `Log` file is neccessary? Will there be any other methods to it?  
Also, can you access the `'EnvConfig'` from both files? Are they in the same folder? Why is there a neccessity to read the `logfilename` in a separate file?

Comment: what i did is removed the class which resolved the issue.